# Statement not working properly

Tags: php, class

i have a script in a class, when i try to get the script to check something it doesn't finish. It just stops for some reason, here's my script:

```
case 'f':
    if (isset($this->packet['f']['v'])) {
        return $this->sendMessage("user  is online");
    }
    $this->sendMessage("User is offline.");
break;
```

So basically if the user was  online, it would return that the user is online which it does. but if he's not it wouldn't say "User is offline" whats the problem?

Comment: Post the surrounding code. This is not syntactically invalid. And turn on `display_errors` so you can see the fatal error:  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Is this code, by any chance, in the method `sendMessage`?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Does `sendMessage` have a return value?  What is it?

Comment: @awm yes. And no i don't have it on but im going to check.

Comment: I did not get any errors when i tried it.

Comment: Why isn't there a `return` in front of `$this->sendMessage("User is offline.");`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case 'f':
    return (isset($this->packet['f']['v']) ? $this->sendMessage("User is online") : $this->sendMessage("User is offline."));
    break;
```

Comment: What's the error? Since this is just a ternary if/else, it sounds like the error is either with `$this->packet['f']['v']` or `$this->sendMessage()`. Hard to say without knowing the error though...